# How dynamically create array in php with string index

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-programming

I've a string like this:

```
$str = "eat.fruit.apple.good";
```

I've to use this array like this:

```
$arr["eat"]["fruit"]["apple"]["good"] = true;
```

But I don't understand how can I create it dynamically.
Thanks
Davide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = "eat.fruit.apple.good";
// Set pointer at top of the array 
$arr = array();
$path = &$arr;
// Path is joined by dots
foreach (explode('.', $str) as $p) 
   // Make a next step
   $path = &$path[$p];
$path = true;
print_r($arr); // $arr["eat"]["fruit"]["apple"]["good"] = true;
```

**UPDATE** Variant without pointer:

```
$str = "eat.fruit.apple.good";

$res = 'true';
foreach(array_reverse(explode('.', $str)) as $i) 
   $res = '{"' . $i . '":' . $res . '}'; 
$arr = json_decode($res, true);
```

Comment: Very neat solution!

Comment: Not bad at all ...

Comment: What a genius. Thanks man. How can I make this working if I don't want to use pointers?

Comment: I don't understand why? but i've added variant without pointer

Comment: Thanks thank thanks man. I need it because I'm making a software with php and js, but js I read has no pointer.

Comment: Hello @splash58 Thanks a lot for this code. You are a genius.